# Javascript timer - How do I prevent the timer from speeding up each time .deck is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a memory card game. the class .deck represents a deck of cards. Each time I click a card the timer speeds up. How do I prevent the timer from speeding up?

```
function startTimer() { 
    $(".deck").on("click", function () {
        nowTime = setInterval(function () {
            $timer.text(`${second}`)
            second = second + 1
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not speeding up. You're starting a new timer on every click, and they're all running in the background. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want a timer to start once the user clicks on a card, and for the timer to continue counting normally as more cards are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You start multiple intervals, one each click. You probably should just start one. If you want to start it for the first card that is clicked:

```
function startTimer() {
    // Maybe remove old timer? Should happen somewhere in your code.
    // Possibly "stopTimer" if you have such a function.
    clearInterval(nowTime);

    let started = false;
    $(".deck").on("click", function () {
        if (started) return;

        nowTime = setInterval(function () {
            $timer.text(`${second}`)
            second = second + 1
        }, 1000);
        started = true;
    });
}
```

That code should have some more cleanup, though. Otherwise you accumulate a lot of dead event listeners.

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Comment: The `clearInterval()` call makes the `started` code irrelevant.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: No. `clearInterval` is there for last "game". Though it probably belongs in another function. `started` is there so only one button starts the timer, otherwise the original problem of many simultaneous timers would still exist.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have your `clearInterval` outside of the `click` event. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the previous timer before starting a new one because, if you don't, you wind up with multiple timer callback functions all executing one immediately after the other, which gives the illusion that your single timer is speeding up.

```
function startTimer() { 
  $(".deck").on("click", function () {
    clearInterval(nowTime);  // Stop previous timer

    nowTime = setInterval(function () {
      $timer.text(`${second}`);
      second = second + 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Another way to deal with this is to only allow the `click` event callback to run the very first time the button is clicked:

```
function startTimer() { 
  $(".deck").on("click", timer);

  function timer() {
    nowTime = setInterval(function () {
      $timer.text(`${second}`);
      second = second + 1;
    }, 1000);
   $(".deck").off("click", timer); // Remove the click event handler
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, would not recommend the first method. It cuts the intervals short and starts new ones, leading to inaccurate timing.

Comment: @H.B. Understood, but it answers the question. And, the delay could/should be cut down anyway because even with a single timer, 1000 ms will occasionally cause a second to get skipped.

Comment: Why would a second get skipped? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: The delay is only the minimal amount of time your timer "might" take to run. It's not an exact guarantee. By setting it to one second, it could very well wind up delaying more than a second. So, if the time was .95 of a second and the delay worked out to be 1.06 seconds, you'd miss the one second mark and skip straight to 2 seconds. Setting a smaller delay (say 200ms) reduces (but doesn't eliminate) that chance. This relates to showing the time, which the OP is doing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Do you have a source for that? I expected the callback to simply execute as soon as possible after the elapsed time, i.e. being pushed to the event queue and run as soon as it reaches its turn.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, that is how it works, but "as soon as possible" could mean longer than the delay value. I see this behavior quite a bit when people make a simple "clock" on a page with a `1000ms` delay. You will occasionally see the seconds skip ahead by one. Decreasing the delay combats this.

Comment: That is not the same. If it were to execute as soon as possible it would sometimes be off by a few milliseconds and be quite accurate most of the time. There should not be any large skips if that were the logic. I'll go read the spec...

Comment: @H.B. Not sure you're following. The delay you set is just an indication of when to place the callback in the event loop. It's not a guaranteed time to execution of the callback. Just because you may set `1000` does not mean your callback will run in one second. In that case 1 second would be the absolute minimum time you could expect your callback to run. If you were displaying a clock and the exact time was 3:43:09 (and .95 of the way to 3:43:10) PM and your callback function ran exactly 1 second later, your clock would correctly show 3:43:10 PM, but ....

Comment: I think i get where you are going. But this code keeps its own timer and does not query system time.

Comment: @H.B. ... if your callback took just a little longer to run, say 1.06 seconds, the displayed time would jump from 3:43:09 PM to 3:43:11 PM.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, that's true, this particular scenario doesn't use the system time, so it really is not so much of a factor here. Of course, the OP doesn't show us the declaration of `second`, so we can't be entirely sure.

Comment: Which is why method one is really not a good idea. Because it introduces *a lot* of inaccuracy which would not be the case if it were to use the system time.